# How to load this code on function.php

Tags: hooks, query-string

guys, this is my first question here, Thank you so much in advance.

I'm trying to integrate a code on every product page But it created some conflict:

```
function print_my_inline_script() {
  if ( wp_script_is( 'some-script-handle', 'done' ) ) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">


<div id="BVRRContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $BV.ui( 'rr', 'show_reviews', {
      doShowContent : function () { 
         // If the container is hidden (such as behind a tab), put code here to make it visible 
         //(open the tab).
      }
   });
</script>


</script>
<?php
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'print_my_inline_script' );
```

Any help ?

Comment: What conflict? What error are you seeing?

Comment: i am not sure but i think you can not like that write a div tag inside script use some other method for it. Give some link check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096820/html-tag-inside-javascript  AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216391/include-html-code-in-js

Answer (score 1):

Without any further detail (error messages, etc), we're just guessing here.

I first thought of the `print_my_inline_script()` function as being doubly defined, but then it looked to me like you have a `<script>` within a `<script>`.

Remove the outside `<script> </script>` commands and see what that does.